# Bash remote ssh command is not working because of premature expansion

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, command-line

I'm trying to delete the contents of a remote directory in a bash script and leaving the folder intact by using ssh like this:

```
# First attempt
inboxResult=$(ssh -t -t username@host sudo -u rootUser rm -Rf /my/path/here/inbox/*)

# Second attempt
inboxResult=`ssh -t -t username@host sudo -u rootUser rm -Rf /my/path/here/inbox/*`
```

but it keeps failing silently. I've done my research and it seems like the '*' is being expanded before the command is sent via ssh to the remote host, but I would want the opposite. I couldn't find any solution and I've tried more than these two but they seem to be far from what I was looking.

Comment: `inboxResult=$(ssh -t -t username@host 'sudo -u rootUser rm -Rf /my/path/here/inbox/*')`?

Comment: I'm afraid your solution does not work, @Cyrus. It didn't delete anything